# How to reinstall ubuntu phone camera app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, camera

I have uninstalled camera application on my bq Aquaris E4.5 by long-tapping on the app icon and choosing "uninstall" and now cannot install it back since "Camera" query does not show it in app store. I'm on the stable channel, the problem exists on OTA-8 and OTA-8.5. Does anybody know how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, I have the same problem on my Nexus 4. But the clock appeared can be uninstalled and reinstalled. It can be found in app store. The camera not. This is scary.

Answer (score 1):

Try the workaround provided [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/camera-app/+question/277509).

Open the terminal app on the phone (or alternatively connect to desktop and use adb) and run:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo apt-get install camera-app
```

---

#### Known issue

Two functioning camera icons in app menu, one updated, one stuck on old version (see comment #5 of [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1528955)) although not experienced by all the users who tried this solution (see comment #7 of the [same bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1528955)).

Answer (score 0):

After I switched to the rc-proposed channel I was able to find the camera app in app store and to install it successfully. :-)

Nevertheless switching back to stable channel removed the camera app again and it was no longer in app store.

UPDATE:
I just returned to the stable channel and thus camera app was installed automatically. Nevertheless, the app can still be uninstalled but can not be found in app store!
I opened a BugReport here: [Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1528955)